# Cakephp redirect to referer without login

Tags: cakephp

I try redirect user to referer page but without authorize $this->referer return "/". For example user try access /messages/add page and redirect login page to authorize but in login action i dont access /messages/add with pr($this->referer()) my code below. Sorry for bad english

```
public function login() {
    pr($this->referer());
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
```

Comment: Use the good old `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']`

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP have authentication component that can easily solve your problem.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Read up on `loginAction`,`loginRedirect` function. Loginredirect will redirect you to the referer if the login is successful.